# Find value in array of objects after importing from CSV file

Tags: powershell

I am reading in values from a CSV file using Import-Csv which include server name, ip address and a note field

Is there a built in mechanism to find an object based on the server name without having to loop through the entire array?

I'm keeping the array in memory to use multiple times.

```
$ServerList = Import-Csv ".\ServerList.csv"
```

I'm creating a GUI with Powershell Studio and populating a dropdown with all the server names read in from the file.  The user will choose a server from the dropdown and there will be buttons to perform actions on that server using the IP address read in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could populate a hashtable with the data from the CSV, using the servername as key:

```
$ServerList = @{}
Import-Csv '.\ServerList.csv' | % { $ServerList[$_.ServerName] = $_ }
```

That way you can access the data like this:

```
$server = 'foo'
$ServerList[$server].IPAddress
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = Import-csv my.csv | where {$_.servername -eq "MyServer"}
foreach ($server in $csv) {
 # Do your thing
}
```

Comment: I did not mention that I'm keeping the array around to access multiple times

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call it multiple times you can use a function that you call when the user selects a server:

```
function getServer($selectedServer){
    $ServerInfo = Import-Csv ".\ServerList.csv" | where {$_.servername -eq $selectedServer}
    return $ServerInfo 
}
```

When the user makes a selection the code would like like so:

```
$Server = getServer('ABCSRV')
```

Then `$Server.IP` and `$Server.Notes` would have the information from that specific server, granted that you have these columns in place in your csv.